# How to render javascript markers on google maps in WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, android-webview

I am trying to render javascript markers on google maps in WebView, but markers are not showing in WebView.
I have set

```
        binding.webView.setWebViewClient(webViewHelper);
        binding.webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        binding.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        binding.webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        binding.webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        binding.webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        binding.webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        binding.webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        binding.webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        binding.webView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        binding.webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```

in WebView Settings. Map is rendered but still not showing the markers. Markers are showing outside of WebView. Does anyone have any solution on how to render javascript markers on WebView?

Comment: Are you doing this using the standard Google Maps API, or is this specific to Android's implementation of Google Maps? If it's the former, can you share what your current markers implementation is as well as whether or not this is working outside of the Android WebView element?

Comment: Markers are showing outside of the Android WebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the developer documentation adding `webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode (MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);`
fixed the issue.